# When trying to browse to an .aspx page I get the error The referenced file '/application.master' is not allowed on this page

Tags: wss-3.0, error

We are using wss 3.0. We have a data entry form that is just an .aspx page. When browsing to it on one machine after deploying the .wsp we get the error

The referenced file '/application.master' is not allowed on this page

This project is deployed on another machine and it loads fine. What would cause this issue? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That is not a valid path. Can you post the top 3 lines of the aspx page?